# How to send traces generated to OpenTelemetry collector?

Tags: go, newrelic, open-telemetry

I have instrumented the code to generate traces and print them in the terminal. Now, how do I receive them in OpenTelemetry Collector to export them to NewRelic? Language used: Golang

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the [New Relic Docs](https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/more-integrations/open-source-telemetry-integrations/opentelemetry/opentelemetry-setup/#view-data) you can simply configure the [OTLP gRPC exporter](https://pkg.go.dev/go.opentelemetry.io/otel/exporters/otlp/otlptrace/otlptracegrpc) in Go code with https://otlp.nr-data.net as endpoint. Also API Key in header.

Or

You can use an Opentelemetry collector running as a separate service with NewRelic as exporter. [sample config](https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/more-integrations/open-source-telemetry-integrations/opentelemetry/collector/opentelemetry-collector-basic)

Answer (score 0):

I'm also new to OpenTelemetry, but maybe [this link](https://opentelemetry.io/docs/collector/getting-started/#local) would be useful. Checkout the "Local" section. There you will find the link to opentelemetry-collector-contrib repository, where in examples/demo/client you can find an example.